Why does EarlyStopping.stopped_epoch gives one less than actuall last epoch
Im training a regresive model using keras.
In the code Ive putted that it has to print Last epoch and Best epoch, just to keep track of it, and all the time it gives last epoch as one less, not to say that sometimes it sets the best epoch as something that it isnt, cause I have the MSE as the value to measure and sometimes I get things like this:
Epoch 9/50
90/90 [==============================] - 3s 36ms/step - loss: 5.4706e-04 - root_mean_squared_error: 0.0234
Epoch 10/50
90/90 [==============================] - 3s 34ms/step - loss: 5.1254e-04 - root_mean_squared_error: 0.0226
Epoch 11/50
90/90 [==============================] - 3s 35ms/step - loss: 6.2349e-04 - root_mean_squared_error: 0.0250
Epoch 12/50
90/90 [==============================] - 3s 35ms/step - loss: 6.0034e-04 - root_mean_squared_error: 0.0245
Epoch 13/50
90/90 [==============================] - 3s 34ms/step - loss: 5.7258e-04 - root_mean_squared_error: 0.0239
Epoch 14/50
90/90 [==============================] - 3s 35ms/step - loss: 6.1547e-04 - root_mean_squared_error: 0.0248
Epoch 15/50
90/90 [==============================] - 3s 35ms/step - loss: 5.4814e-04 - root_mean_squared_error: 0.0234
Epoch 16/50
90/90 [==============================] - 3s 38ms/step - loss: 5.3549e-04 - root_mean_squared_error: 0.0231

Best epoch: 9
Last Epoch: 15

In this ej, we can see what I sayed, that the last epoch doesnt match the number printed, which is always 1 less, and in this ej we can also see that the best epoch is sayed to be the epoch 9, when clearly the epoch 10 (just the following one, and this happens always) is better, and in this particular case, epoch number 16 is also better than epoch 9 (Although this is not so frequent).
My code is the following one:

# Train the model
earlystopping = callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor="loss", mode="min", patience=6, restore_best_weights=True)

self.model.fit(x_train , y_train, batch_size=24, epochs=50, callbacks=[earlystopping])

print(f'\nBest epoch: {earlystopping.best_epoch}\nLast Epoch: {earlystopping.stopped_epoch}\n')

It might have something to do with indexes, IDK if epochs when stored get stored in an array or list, and therefore, when getting the value for EarlyStopping.<some_epoch>, it gives you its index value, so its one less, because instead of counting from 1, it starts counting at 0.
The weird part is with the best epoch. What is wrong with my code that it doesnt identify better epochs (like in the case portraited above), because on most cases it might be the same reason as for last epoch, indexes, but somethimes, some epoch in between the best epoch 1 and the last epoch is better than the categorized as the best epoch.
